# pregmatch not working as intended

Tags: php, validation, url, preg-match

why is the below url validation giving me errors. If I put url = www.google.ca, it gives me a false url.

```
function validateURL($url){
$regex = "((https?|ftp)://)?";  
$regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=$_.-]+(:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=$_.-]+)?@)?"; 
$regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*).([a-z]{2,3})"; 
$regex .= "(:[0-9]{2,5})?";  
$regex .= "(/([a-z0-9+$_-].?)+)*/?";  
$regex .= "(?[a-z+&$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+/$_.-]*)?";  
$regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+$_.-]*)?";  
if(preg_match('/^$regex$/', $url)) 
{ 
echo $url."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;=".'<font color="blue">Valid URL</font>'; 
} 
else {
echo $url."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;=".'<font color="red">Invalid URL</font>';
}
}

$url = 'www.google.ca';

validateURL($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why this doesn't work.

1. Variables are not evaluated when enclosed with `'`s. Therefore, `'/^$regex$/'` will be evaluated exactly as it's written.
2. Anything with a `$` enclosed with `"`'s will get evaluated. Therefore, stuff like `$_` will be replaced with the contents of the variable `$_` if it exists.
3. You need to escape backslashes and question marks in your `$regex` variable.

This will work:

```
function validateURL($url) {
    $regex = '((https?|ftp):\/\/)?';  
    $regex .= '([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=$_.-]+(:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=$_.-]+)?@)?'; 
    $regex .= '([a-z0-9-.]*).([a-z]{2,3})'; 
    $regex .= '(:[0-9]{2,5})?';  
    $regex .= '(\/([a-z0-9+$_-].?)+)*\/?';  
    $regex .= '(\?[a-z+&$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/$_.-]*)?';  
    $regex .= '(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+$_.-]*)?';  
    return preg_match("/^{$regex}$/", $url) > 0;
}

$url = 'www.google.ca';

if (validateURL($url))
    print "$url is valid\n";
else
    print "$url is invalid\n";
```

Comment: `if(preg_match("/^$regex$/", $url)) ` ... i get the following error if i do that Unknown modifier '/'

Comment: You haven't escaped backslashes then.

Comment: .kk i dont get the escaping error anymore. but you sure the validation works, i put `$url = "wwjw..google.ca"` and it said it was valid

Comment: @Anonymous I haven't changed what your regular expression does.